# Curl appends to Content-Type when sending a form, how to override this?

Tags: url, curl, header, mime-types

Take this example:

```
curl http://host.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/oauth2/token -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -F 'grant_type=password' -F 'username=test-user' -F 'password=password' -F 'client_id=test_application_client_id' -F 'client_secret=password' -v
```

One would think `Content-Type` would be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Instead Curl sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=------------------------5f55da42226c00e5`

Is there a way to *not* do this?

```
jonathanfisher@odin ~/ $ curl http://something.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/oauth2/token -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -F 'grant_type=password' -F 'username=test-user' -F 'password=password' -F 'client_id=test_application_client_id' -F 'client_secret=password' -v
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to something.compute-1.amazonaws.com (0.0.0.0) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: something.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 598
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=------------------------5f55da42226c00e5
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 00:43:13 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 145
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
WebApplicationException has been caught, status: 400, message: The Content-Type header is missing on this request you should define: Content-Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From curl manpage :

> -F, --form 
>                 (HTTP)  This  lets  curl  emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST
>   data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.
>                 This enables uploading of binary files etc.

**Have you tried replacing your `-F` with `-d`?**

Here is what I get with both:

## With `-F`:

```
$ curl -F "param1=value1&param2=value2" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://google.com -v
* About to connect() to google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2a00:1450:400a:807::200e...
* Connected to google.com (2a00:1450:400a:807::200e) port 80 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: google.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 161
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=----------------------------5bb04ed0c4fe
>
```

## With `-d` :

```
$ curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://google.com -v
* About to connect() to google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2a00:1450:400a:807::200e...
* Connected to google.com (2a00:1450:400a:807::200e) port 80 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: google.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 27
>
```